# Having troubles with nested states in AngularJS and ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Have some troubles with nested states...

I have an application which has a few pages (represented as page templates).
So, I really need to use nested states. Reading [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and examples was useless...

So the code is here.

This is my states configuration:

```
myApplication.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
            url: '/state1',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: /* path to template */
                },
                'menu': {
                    templateUrl: /* path to template */
                },
                'overlay': {
                    templateUrl: /* path to template */
                }
            }
        })
        .state('layer', {
            url: '/layer',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: /* path to template */
                },
                'menu': {
                    templateUrl: /* path to template */
                }
            }       
        })
        .state('layer.message', {
            url: '/message',
            views: {
                'overlay': {
                    templateUrl: /* path to template */
                }
            }
        });
});
```

And this is my HTML view:

```
<html>
    <body ng-app="myApplication" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Here is some not interesting stuff -->
        </div>

        <!-- But here is the most exciting things -->
        <div id = "overlay" ui-view="overlay"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have a state 'layer' and a substate 'layer.message' in this substate I just want to load one extra template which is called `overlay` and wrap it in a `div` tag, like in 'state1'.
But all my tries are failed. The firebug debugging tool shows me that template was loaded via GET query. But it doesn't appear in HTML model and therefore it doesn't render. In 'state1' everething is ok.
I believe I'm doing something wrong with nasted states... Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the url in that case. It should be `/layer/message`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your nested `layer.message` state needs to address the view in the higher state explicitly using an '@' suffix, ie.:

```
.state('layer.message', {
        url: '/message',
        views: {
            'overlay@': {
                templateUrl: /* path to template */
            }
        }
    })
```

This says 'use the template to populate the view called "overlay" in the unnamed (root) state'.  You could also be more explicit and specify `overlay@layer`.

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names for more details.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. One symbol '@' did everything I need. )

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working! I've edited my answer to provide a reference to the docs where this is outlined too.